can't update and delete employee because id field is undefined
Created application in spring boot as backend and angular as frontend , data is properly getting from API checked in Postman API plateform(perform all CRUD properly on POSTMAN Plateform) ,In Angular data fetched except id, employee is created properly through angular,but can't perform operation of Update and delete , as it gives console error "Id is UNDEFINED"
enter image description here
enter image description here
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Employee } from '../model/employee';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EmployeeService {
  private baseUrl = "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/employees";
  employees: Employee[] | undefined;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  addEmployee(emp: Employee): Observable<Employee> {
    return this.http.post<Employee>(this.baseUrl, emp)
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError)
      );
  }

  getAllEmployees(): Observable<Employee[]> {
    return this.http.get<Employee[]>(this.baseUrl)
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError)
      );
      console.log(this.employees);
  }

  updateEmployee(emp: Employee): Observable<Employee> {
    const url = `${this.baseUrl}/${emp.id}`;
    return this.http.put<Employee>(url, emp)
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError)
      );
  }

  deleteEmployee(emp: Employee): Observable<Employee> {
    const url = `${this.baseUrl}/${emp.id}`;
    return this.http.delete<Employee>(url)
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError)
      );
  }

  private handleError(error: any) {
    console.error('API Error: ', error);
    return throwError(error);
  }
}


import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Employee } from '../../model/employee';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { EmployeeService } from '../../service/employee.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  empDetail !: FormGroup;
  empObj : Employee = new Employee();
  empList : Employee[] = [];

  constructor(private formBuilder : FormBuilder, private empService : EmployeeService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.getAllEmployee();

    this.empDetail = this.formBuilder.group({
      id : [''],
      firstName : [''],
      lastName : [''],
      emailId : ['']
    });    
    this.getAllEmployee();
  }

  addEmployee() {
    console.log(this.empDetail);
    this.empObj.id = this.empDetail.value.id;
    this.empObj.firstName = this.empDetail.value.firstName;
    this.empObj.lastName = this.empDetail.value.lastName;
    this.empObj.emailId = this.empDetail.value.emailId;

    this.empService.addEmployee(this.empObj).subscribe({
     next: (res)=>{
        console.log(res);
        this.getAllEmployee();
    },error: err=>{
        console.log(err);
    }});

  }

  getAllEmployee() {
    this.empService.getAllEmployees().subscribe({
      next:(res)=>{
        this.empList = res;
    },error:err=>{
      console.log("error while fetching data.")
    }});
  }

  editEmployee(employee: Employee) {
    if (!employee|| !employee.id) {
      console.error('Employee data or ID is undefined');
      return;
    }
  
    this.empDetail.setValue({
      id: employee.id || '',
      firstName: employee.firstName || '',
      lastName: employee.lastName || '',
      emailId: employee.emailId || ''
    });
  }
  updateEmployee() {
    if (!this.empObj || !this.empObj.id) {
      console.error('Employee data or ID is undefined');
      return;
    }
    this.empObj.id = this.empDetail.value.id;
    this.empObj.firstName = this.empDetail.value.firstName;
    this.empObj.lastName = this.empDetail.value.lastName;
    this.empObj.emailId = this.empDetail.value.emailId;

    this.empService.updateEmployee(this.empObj).subscribe({
      next:(res)=>{
      console.log(res);
      this.getAllEmployee();
    },error: err=>{
      console.log(err);
    }})

  }

  deleteEmployee(emp : Employee) {
    if (!emp || !emp.id) {
      console.error('Employee data or ID is undefined');
      return;
    }
  
    this.empService.deleteEmployee(emp).subscribe({
      next: (res) => {
        console.log(res);
        alert('Employee deleted successfully');
        this.getAllEmployee();
      },
      error: (err) => {
        console.log(err);
      }
    });
  }

}


enter image description here
enter image description here
I am trying to add more validation to find exact problem , but conclusion I am getting is there is something blocking ID field in angular side so can't perform operation, I just want to help to resolve this problem

UPDATE:
You need to rename all id properties into empid, same things needs to be done for HTML.
You are having empid returned from java layer, but you are trying to access id field which does not exist.

The get route of java code, is not returning the employee id field, fix that and the update and delete will start working.
In the below screenshot you can see there is no ID field values.


https://i.sstatic.net/yr6QD6J0.png  Routing is already given in java code , on Postman API it return Employee ID but its blocking in Angular side

@swatikadu please share the API response for get all data

@swatikadu updated my answer!

got the solution , there is mapping problem at frontend side, my db colum name is empId and in angular I give only id thats why it not working , nut i made correction its work fine now .. Thanks for help
